# Creating a new data table for each row of an existing data table R while avoiding memory vector issue

Tags: r, matrix, merge, dplyr, data.table

Suppose I have two data tables:

```
library(data.table)
A=data.table(w=1:3,d=5:7)
B=data.table(K=2:4,m=9:11)


> A
   w d
1: 1 5
2: 2 6
3: 3 7
> B
   K  m
1: 2  9
2: 3 10
3: 4 11
```

I want to do the following expansion, where I have a new B for each row of A:

```
C=A[,B[],by=names(A)]

   w d K  m
1: 1 5 2  9
2: 1 5 3 10
3: 1 5 4 11
4: 2 6 2  9
5: 2 6 3 10
6: 2 6 4 11
7: 3 7 2  9
8: 3 7 3 10
9: 3 7 4 11
```

However, when I do it with my real data, I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(A, , B[], by = names(A)) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

It turns out this is a memory error.  However, I think there should be a way to do this without loops, memory is not an issue on my server up to 50gb of ram, which the following data table would certainly be less than.

Does anyone know an efficient way to do this?

Comment: what version of data.table are you using? what is nrow(A)*nrow(B)?

Comment: you might try CJ(iA, iB) where ik is seq_len(nrow(k)), then using `set` in a for loop first over A's columns (using iA) then over B's (using iB). if there's a real memory issue this will help pin it down more accurately

Comment: I'm not even sure what your code does. Try something like `C <- A[rep(1:.N, each = nrow(B))][, (names(B)) := B]` perhaps.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's data.table related error. Looks like you hit some limit in R. According to [BDR](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-in-merge-negative-length-vectors-are-not-allowed-td4692216.html) your problem is due to trying to create a result longer than 2^31 rows. I think you need to rethink why you need such result in the first place. If this some pre-processing step, it might be helpful to tell us what is the end result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidArenburg `B[]`  will be treated as a list, and it's operating `by` all columns. so the code should be the same as yours. but yes, seems likely that the long vector issue is the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky way to handle this might be to add an identical helper column to each table and then to allow cartesian joins:

```
library(data.table)
A = data.table(w = 1:3, d = 5:7)
B = data.table(K = 2:4, m = 9:11)

A[, j := 1]
B[, j := 1]

C = A[B, on = 'j', allow.cartesian = T]
```